# What is the possible minimum dimension for this linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

## Problem

Five nonzero vectors $v_1$ to $v_5$ in $V$,
$$
a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 + a_4v_4+ a_5v_5 \neq 0
$$
whenever all $a_i$ are nonzero.

What is the possible minimum dimension of the linear space $V$?

## My thinking

The condition is equal to
$$
a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 + a_4v_4+ a_5v_5 = 0
\Rightarrow
\exists i, a_i = 0
$$
which is weaker than the condition for the dimension.
I can exclude the case when $dim(V)=1$, but what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Choose two non-zero and linearly independent vectors $w$ and $z$ in $V$ and put $v_1 = w$, $v_2 = v_3 = v_4 = v_5 = z$. Then the condition is satisfied.